# OpenLayers3 change Layer source URL (or replace features loaded from another URL)

Tags: openlayers-3

I have a map with a Vector layer, containing features from a GeoJSON source:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [new ol.layer.Tile({
                 source: new ol.source.OSM()
             }),
             new ol.layer.Vector({
                 source: new ol.source.Vector({
                     url: 'http://example.com:5000/geo/data/zones/1',
                     format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
                 }),
             })],
    renderer: 'canvas',
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [737514.438475665, 5864533.629390752],
        zoom: 13
    })
});
```

I have multiple URLs that returns s GeoJSON string:

- `http://example.com:5000/geo/data/zones/1`
- `http://example.com:5000/geo/data/zones/2`
- `http://example.com:5000/geo/data/zones/n`

**I need to be able to switch the URL of my Layer source (or fetch and display features from another URL).**

I have tried to find the 'url' property on the ol.Layer.Vector instance:

```
l=m.getLayers().getArray()[1]
l.getProperties()
```

and on the ol.source.Vector instance:

```
s = l.getSource()
s.getProperties()
```

but I haven't found anything about the 'url' property.

---

Could you provide a way to do that ?

- is it possible to simply update the source URL (and automagically refresh the layer features) ?
- shall I remove existing features, load new features using my own logic and add the loaded ones ?
- shall I remove the whole Layer, re-create it, and re-add it ?

Comment: How about a [LayerGroup](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/examples/layer-group.html)?

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you need further explanation? I am not sure, but I might have been a bit vague on the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - is it possible to simply update the source URL (and automagically refresh the layer features) ?

You can create a new source and set it on the target layer using [ol.layer.Layer.setSource](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.layer.Layer.html#setSource).

```
s=new ol.source.Vector(/* your source config goes here */);
l=m.getLayers().getArray()[1];
l.setSource(s);
```

If both layers are visible, the map will automagically refresh the features.

> - shall I remove existing features, load new features using my own logic and add the loaded ones ?

You can add or remove features on your Vector Layer using:

- [ol.layer.Vector.addFeature](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#addFeature)
- [ol.layer.Vector.addFeatures](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#addFeatures)
- [ol.layer.Vector.removeFeature](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#removeFeature)

See also: [ol.Feature](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.Feature.html) and [ol.layer.Vector.forEachFeature](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#forEachFeature)

```
var feature = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Polygon(polyCoords),
  labelPoint: new ol.geom.Point(labelCoords),
  name: 'My Polygon'
});

l=m.getLayers().getArray()[1];
s=l.getSource();
s.addFeature(feature);
s.addFeatures(/* array of features */);
s.removeFeature(feature);
```

> - shall I remove the whole Layer, re-create it, and re-add it ?

You can do that using [ol.Map.addLayer](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#addLayer) and [ol.Map.removeLayer](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/apidoc/ol.Map.html#removeLayer).

```
// m is your map variable
v = new ol.layer.Vector(cfg);
m.addLayer(v);
m.removeLayer(v);
```

**Final answer**

All options listed above will switch the URL of your Layer. Each option triggers its own set of events and works with different parameters and objects. Based on my personal understanding, I would suggest:

- Use option 1, if you are loading a new layer with the same properties of your old layer, but with new data.
- Use option 2, if you have very few changes regarding some features on a Vector layer.
- Use option 3, if you have a whole new layer, with different properties than your previous layer.

Comment: I like your answer. I'm also concerned by the possible perfs/leaks of each option, as I'm drawing 5'000-20'000+ features on the vector layer. Yet I believe the ol3 team is very much concerned about garbage collecting

Comment: I would suggest making it work first, then going for optimization if needed. I had huge problems regarding performance in the past (OpenLayers <1),  while drawing a WFS map with too many features. The geodata I worked with had far too many details and from what I recall, I had to do some work server-side to reduce the amount of data that the browser was receiving. WFS data was too verbose at the time and there wasn't much room to work efficiently on the browser. Here is [the thread](http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2009-November/014799.html) were it all was discussed.

Comment: I used the 3rd option (for now) although I the layer has the same properties. I wrote a little prayer, as a comment, for proper destroying of features.